# ":@wdio/cli:launcher: No specs found to run, exiting with failure" error encountered when running wdio on pre push hook

Tags: git, hook, webdriver-io

Summary:
When I run the wdio.conf.js on the terminal, I am able to run the test but as soon as I run it as part of the git pre-push hook, it then gets the error.

Background:
We keep a separate folder containing the custom git hooks and use `npm install` to copy it to the .git folder. The wdio tests would work properly until I get to the point where I make a commit to include the pre-push hook changes and try to push them.

Has anyone encountered this problem?